# how to map a variable from component to index.html

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I just can't find a simple explanation on how I map a variable in a Component, with the value in the index.html file. I don't need explanation for concrete code, just general idea how it should work.

Let's say I have a component

```
@Component
class Downloader {
    private String version;
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        String result = getResult(name, version);
    }

}
```

And also i have an html file:

```
<html "xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> </head>
<body>
<li> 
HERE I NEED THE VALUE OF MY VARIABLE
"${result}"
 </li>
</body>
</html>
```

What are the steps to get what I want. How should I bind the values?

Answer (score 0):

Spring provide you various type classes and interfaces to utilize your user and your user's data. According to your code, can't forward **result** data ***java*** class to ***html*** page. Because there are no bride between them. To do that, you need to take help of `Model` interface or `ModelAndView` class.

```
@Component
class Downloader {
    private String version;
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(Model model) {
        String result = getResult(name, version);
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
    }

}
```

Now here you get your value.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> </head>
<body>
<li> 
HERE I NEED THE VALUE OF MY VARIABLE
"${result}"
 </li>
</body>
</html>
```